# Confusing product of characters

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\chi$ be a dirichlet character on $\mathbb{Z}/12 \mathbb{Z}$ defined by

$$ \chi(1) = 1 \quad \chi(5)=-1 \quad \chi(7) = -1 \quad \chi(11) = 1 $$

and $\psi$ a dirichlet character on $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\psi(1)=\psi(2)=-1$.

Apparently $\chi\psi$ on $(\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $ has values

$$ \chi\psi(1) = 1 \quad \chi\psi(5) = 1 \quad \chi\psi(7) = -1 \quad \chi\psi(11) = -1$$

How are these values computed? Clearly e.g. $\chi(1)\psi(1) = -1$ which already contradicts the example. I understand that the product character is actually the primitive character associated to the product in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, but in order to compute it I need to find the pointwise values and they seem wrong.

Comment: Once you'll have corrected your character $\bmod 3$, do you see how it induces a character $\bmod 12$ ? Multiply the latter with $\chi$ to get $\chi \psi$.

Comment: Yes, by periodicity I guess. But what do you mean correct my character mod 3?

Comment: Oh you mean my character mod 3 *must* be a typo since characters send 1 to 1?

Comment: Are you considering characters of the additive group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, or characters of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ ? I'm confused about how your $\psi$ is being upgraded from a character of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ (or $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^{\times}$  ?) to $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)^{\times}$.

Comment: @Suzet always multiplicative group of units in all cases, sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: @Karl All right, then there is an issue with your definition of $\psi$. You write $\psi(1) = -1$, but that is not possible as any group character sends the neutral element to $1$.